# Is there an easier way to find regex of the string?

Tags: regex

I'm just beginning with regex and just got stuck in a difficult situation.
The string i have is:

```
ITEM DESCRIPTION:  KING AUTHUR 2LB FLOUR     PACK: 10                              SIZE: 0011.00 OZ
```

I need to get the parts within "< >":

```
ITEM DESCRIPTION:  <KING AUTHUR 2LB FLOUR>     PACK: <10>                              SIZE: <0011.00 OZ>
```

I've tried

```
: *([\w\.]+ ?[\w]* [\d\w]* *[\w]*)
```

which is not 100% accurate and feels repetitive and also becomes tedious when the text gets longer (multiple key:value).

Is there a generalized way of getting all the values from a key:value pair from a text of indefinite length?
And also why something like `(ITEM).*:` doesn't stop at `ITEM DESCRIPTION:` but selects all the way upto `ITEM DESCRIPTION: ... SIZE:` if I just want to get the first key?

Comment: Try `:\s*(.*?)(?=\s*\w+:|$)`, see https://regex101.com/r/MRuRF7/1

Comment: The answer to your last question is because `*` is "greedy", it tries to find the longest possible match. So `.*:` will keep going until it reaches the last `:`. Use `*?` to make it non-greedy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way with a PCRE-compatible regex:

```php
:\s*\K.*?(?=\s*\w+:|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cGRUia/1).
An ECMAScript 2018+/.NET/Python PyPi `regex` compliant pattern is

```cs
(?<=:\s*\b).*?(?=\s*\w+:|$)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cGRUia/2).

For the rest, you may rely on capturing:

```js
:\s*(.*?)(?=\s*\w+:|$)
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MRuRF7/1).

*Details*:

- `:\s*` - a colon and zero or more whitespaces
- `\K` - a match reset operator that discards the whole text matched so far from the match memory buffer
- `(?<=:\s*\b)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `:`, zero or more whitespaces and a word boundary
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=\s*\w+:|$)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location in string that is immediately followed with zero or more whitespaces, one or more word chars and then a colon, or end of string.